# Random code generator

Tags: php

I'd like to have a random code generator, written in PHP, that will generate a mixed case code similar to http://jsfiddle.net/**UtKYn**

Before I start re-inventing the wheel, perhaps someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

---

UPDATE:

JS fiddle was just an example of the code they generate for each code project.
Mixed case can increase the number of the combinations while keeping it fairly short.

I found the following function. What is the probability of it generating a duplicate? Do i need to add a db query to check for dupes against other codes stored in db?

```
function rand_string($min = "8", $max = "30") 
{
    $code = NULL;
    for($i=0;$i<$min;$i++) 
    {
        $char = chr(rand(48,122));
        while(!ereg("[a-zA-Z0-9]", $char))
        {
            if($char == $lchar) { continue; }
            $char = chr(rand(48,90));
        }
      $pass .= $char;
      $lchar = $char;
    }
    return $pass;
}
```

Comment: I think you linked to the wrong jsfiddle. Also, what does the mixed-case matter for?

Comment: @Jared: I don't think the jsfiddle was the point. The point was that OP wants to create an identifier like the `UtKYn` portion of the URL.

Comment: Oh right, I see. Thanks AgentConundrum.

Comment: If you are creating a system like bit.ly, tinyurl.com or similar url shortners then yes you will need to have a database connection to check for duplicates. Then a script to take the address and compare it to the database and forward to the corresponding url. If you are creating a url shortner than there is free open source alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple Random String Generator the $characters can be any letters/numbers/special that you may wish. I have used this with all available characters special and regular. You would just pass the length of the random generated string that you want or a default of 8 characters will be generated. Just remove any characters that you wish not to use.

```
 function genRandomString($length = 8) {
     $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`~!@#$%^&*()_+\|]}[{;:<,>.?/';
     $string = '';
     for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
         $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters)-1)];
     }
     return $string;
 }
```

Comment: I like this because I can remove some of the chars that appear similar at times, like l and 1, 0 and O.

Answer (score 2):

The codes those sites are using are just basically base 32 id's. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32 for more information on that.

Regarding checking against unique keys, you will generally want to apply a unique key constraint on the fields, so yes, you either need to check your existing code exists, or check if the insertion failed. However, if you are using an auto increment id and converting it to base 32, you won't need to perform any checks since MySQL is generating a unique id for you.

Comment: PHP's builtin [`base_convert`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) will do the job.

Comment: Is there a PHP function for base32? I am aware of base64_encode but that one generates a long and not so pretty hush string.

Comment: @santa ... PHP's builtin `base_convert` will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this post:

http://blog.kevburnsjr.com/php-unique-hash

It presents a method to create an alphanumeric hash that is unique and will not duplicate (at least until it cycles). This is a much better method than generated random numbers and testing for uniqueness.

Comment: I assume that since you're using primes it doesn't cycle until you exceed the base64 decoded length of the hash, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want random string generation :

http://www.i-fubar.com/random-string-generator.php

http://www.lost-in-code.com/programming/php-code/php-random-string-with-numbers-and-letters/

Comment: If you're going to use either of these, pick the second, not the first.  The first is a horrible, horrible example of how to do such a thing.